# Schema for referencing map elements

Tags: yaml, jsonschema

I'd like to create a jsonschmema for a yaml file that will contain a list of defined keys to be referenced later in the yaml document.

example

```
myDef:
  foo: bar
  baz: lipsum
someProperty:
  refferencedValue: foo
```

the schema should only validate values for `someProperty.refferencedValue` that are listed in `myDef`. So only `foo` and `baz` would be a valid `someProperty.refferencedValue`

is this possible with jsonschema? if so what would this look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In jsonschema it's not possible to reference arbitrary, dynamic values from the data to use it as part of the schema validation. See [this discussion](https://github.com/json-schema-org/json-schema-spec/issues/51) for more context. However:

If you **can enumerate** all possible properties (or property name patterns) of your `myDef` object, you can use `oneOf` to apply specific constraints on the `someProperty.refferencedValue` value for each property.

If you **can't enumerate** all the values you can't use standard jsonschema. Some validator libraries implement *non-standard* features that can help you. For example, [Avj implements a `$data` keyword](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html#data-reference) that can solve your issue. But keep in mind that this solution is tied to Avj - other validators will ignore this keyword.

Comment: Byted, you may be interested in [my data vocabulary](https://json-everything.net/json-schema/#a-vocabulary-for-accessing-data-stored-in-json).  This is actually compatible with JSON Schema whereas ajv's `data` is not.